# Makefile Compiling Issues

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++, openmp

This is my makefile

```
   FC=gfortran
CC=gcc 
CPC=g++ 
FFLAGS = -O3 
LINK=g++
BLASF=dgemmf.o dgemmkernel2.o mult.o
BLASFSRC=dgemmf.f
TIMER=mytimer.o

TGEMM=tgemm
ALL= $(TGEMM)

LIBS = -lblas 

all: $(ALL)
mult.o: 
    $(CPC) -O3 -fopenmp -c mult.cpp

$(TGEMM): tgemm.o mult.o $(TIMER) $(BLASF)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -o $(TGEMM) tgemm.o $(TIMER) $(BLASF) $(LIBS)

dgemmkernel2.o: dgemmkernel2.cpp 
    $(CPC) -O3 -c -fopenmp dgemmkernel2.cpp 
tgemm.o: tgemm.f $(INCLUDE)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c tgemm.f

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(ALL)
```

This is what I get for errors:

```
     make -f makefile_gcc2
gfortran -O3  -c tgemm.f
g++  -O3 -fopenmp -c mult.cpp
gcc     -c -o mytimer.o mytimer.c
gfortran -O3   -c -o dgemmf.o dgemmf.f
g++  -O3 -c -fopenmp dgemmkernel2.cpp 
gfortran -O3  -o tgemm tgemm.o mytimer.o dgemmf.o dgemmkernel2.o mult.o -lblas 
dgemmkernel2.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
mult.o: In function `global constructors keyed to main':
mult.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
mult.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
mult.o: In function `_Z4multPdS_iS_iii.omp_fn.0':
mult.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
mult.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
mult.o: In function `mult(double*, double*, int, double*, int, int, int)':
mult.cpp:(.text+0x175): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
mult.cpp:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_start'
mult.cpp:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_end'
mult.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tgemm] Error 1
```

I understand from my research that these are likely linker issues, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what the problem is.  Is there anyone out there who might have some insight into what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use C++ sources, you should link with the g++ program instead of gfortran. The opposite is true with Intel compilers.

So change:

```
$(TGEMM): tgemm.o mult.o $(TIMER) $(BLASF)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -o $(TGEMM) tgemm.o $(TIMER) $(BLASF) $(LIBS)
```

to

```
$(TGEMM): tgemm.o mult.o $(TIMER) $(BLASF)
    $(LINK) $(FFLAGS) -o $(TGEMM) tgemm.o $(TIMER) $(BLASF) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Tried that, it gives me this now for an error.   I'll see what I can find about it.  /usr/bin/ld: tgemm.o: undefined reference to symbol '_gfortran_set_options@@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '_gfortran_set_options@@GFORTRAN_1.0' is defined in DSO /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3: could not read symbols: Invalid operation

Comment: In which language is your main() function written? Have you tried adding -lgfortran to the $(LIBS) variable?

Comment: It worked, thanks for helping a novice like me out sir/madam!  Much appreciated

Comment: No problem, I've certainly been through this process many times.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem and I solved it by linking with the 'libgomp.dll.a' file -- I use MinGW 4.4.
Or you just have to add to the libirary to link with " -lgomp " e.g. LIBS += -lgomp